# how to put https only in the buying process?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm wanting to put https only on payment pages, but it seems that some conflict happens and these rules do not work together:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^off$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/checkout/
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^on$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/checkout/
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]
```

.htaccess
    
        RewriteEngine On

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^off$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/checkout/
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^on$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/checkout/
    RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !server-status
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Apache version 2.4

Comment: Clarify `rules do not work together`. What error you're getting?